# How to read particular data into arrays from txt file

Tags: c#, regex

I am in learning of C#.

Now I have a text file as follows(it has thousands of lines):

```
    BL51 BANKED LINKER/LOCATER V6.11    10/09/2012  14:39:46  PAGE 1
    ...
    * * * * * * *   C O D E   B A N K   0   * * * * * * *
    BANK0   4000H     09A5H     UNIT         ?CO?MAIN 
    BANK0   49A5H     0289H     UNIT         ?CO?EEPROM
    BANK0   539EH     007DH     UNIT         ?PR?CSCALERPOWERSAVINGRESET?SCALER
    BANK0   541BH     00BFH     UNIT         ?PR?CSCALERRESET?SCALER
    BANK0   54DAH     06BCH     UNIT         ?PR?MODE
    ...
```

I want to read the line start with "BANK0" after string"* * * * * * *   C O D E   B A N K   0   * * * * * * *" and get 0x4000 as integer into array1[0], 0x09A5 into array2[0], 0x49A5 into array1[1], 0x0289 into array2[1] and so on.

can any please help me in this?

Appreciate your help in advance!  :-)

Thanks to Aaron Anodide, I've finished code as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;

namespace _2012_10_24_M51_file_read_into_array_test
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    OpenFileDialog OpenFileDig = new OpenFileDialog();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDig.Filter = "M51 files(*.m51)|*.m51";

        if (OpenFileDig.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            M51TextBox.Text = OpenFileDig.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    // c sharp read text file into array
    /* Nomral C function */
    ArrayList M51Bank = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList M51Offset = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList M51Length = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList M51FunName = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList M51CFile = new ArrayList();

    /* C common code */
    ArrayList M51ComBank = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList M51ComOffset = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList M51ComLength = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList M51ComFunName = new ArrayList();

    static int arrayIdx1 = 0;
    static int arrayIdx2 = 0;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        bool BankStart = false;

        string path = @"D:\xxxx.m51";
        string[] ReadText = File.ReadAllLines(path);            

        for (int idx = 0; idx < ReadText.Length; idx++)
        {
            if (ReadText[idx].Contains("*   C O D E   B A N K   0   *"))
            { 
                // found it do 
                BankStart = true;
            }

            if (ReadText[idx].Contains("OVERLAY MAP OF MODULE:"))
            {
                // found it do 
                BankStart = false;
            }

            if (BankStart == true)
            {
                if ((ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK0")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK1")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK2")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK3")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK4")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK5")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK6")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK7")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK8")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK9")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK10")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK11")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK12")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK13")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK14")
                        || ReadText[idx].Contains("BANK15"))
                    && (ReadText[idx].Contains("?CO?") != true))
                {
                    BANKProc(ReadText[idx]);
                }                        
            }               
        }

        /* */
        int[] m51bank = (int[])M51Bank.ToArray(typeof(int));
        int[] m51Offset = (int[])M51Offset.ToArray(typeof(int));
        int[] m51Length = (int[])M51Length.ToArray(typeof(int));
        string[] m51FunName = (string[])M51FunName.ToArray(typeof(string));
        string[] m51CFile = (string[])M51CFile.ToArray(typeof(string));

        for (int i = 0; i < M51Bank.Count; i++)
        {
            textBox1.Text += (int)m51bank[i] + " ";

            richTextBox1.Text += m51bank[i].ToString("X2");
            richTextBox1.Text += m51Offset[i].ToString("X2") + "\t";
            richTextBox1.Text += m51Length[i].ToString("X2") + "\t";
            richTextBox1.Text += m51FunName[i] + "\t";
            richTextBox1.Text += m51CFile[i] + "\r\n";
        }                                       
    }

    private void BANKProc(string p)
    {            
        string[] NumberSplit = p.Split(new char[]{' ', '\t', 'H','K'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        string[] NameSplit = p.Split(new char[]{'?'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (NameSplit.Length == 4)
        {
            M51Bank.Add(int.Parse(NumberSplit[1], NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            M51Offset.Add(int.Parse(NumberSplit[2], NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            M51Length.Add(int.Parse(NumberSplit[3], NumberStyles.HexNumber));

            M51FunName.Add(NameSplit[2]);
            M51CFile.Add(NameSplit[3]);

            arrayIdx1++;
        }
        else if (NameSplit.Length == 3)
        {
            M51ComBank.Add(int.Parse(NumberSplit[1], NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            M51ComOffset.Add(int.Parse(NumberSplit[2], NumberStyles.HexNumber));
            M51ComLength.Add(int.Parse(NumberSplit[3], NumberStyles.HexNumber));

            M51ComFunName.Add(NameSplit[2]);

            arrayIdx2++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I've just stepped into this question. Time is urgent and i am new to C#. before asking this question, I even don't know what is string.Split ^^. I need to think about the following friends' advice~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some hints for you, assuming you didn't want someone to do the work for you.  Feel free to ask questions about this if you think it might help you.

> I want to read the line start with "BANK0"

- "the line" is a hint that you want to process lines of text one at a time

  - look at File.ReadAllLines()
- "start with BANK0" is hint that you want to use conditional logic and string comparison

> after string"* * * * * * * C O D E B A N K 0 * * * * * * *"

- this is a hint that your program will have states

  - state1: have not yet encountered CODEBANK line
  - state2: have encountered CODEBANK line

> and get 0x4000 as integer into array1[0], 0x09A5 into array2[0], 0x49A5 into array1[1], 0x0289 into array2[1] and so on.

- you need to do further processing on each line of text in order
  to extract individual field values from them

  - look at String.Split()
- you need to convert the string representation of a hexidecimal number
  to an actual value (the type of the value will be given by the type  of array1 and array2)

  - look at int.Parse()

Comment: thank u so much for your great help, this web makes me feel people in the world are so warmhearted. ^^

Comment: Dear Aaron Anodide, I visit your personal profile page, but i don't know how to send you a message, wish you could help me another question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15037840/how-to-reduce-heap-memory-usage-when-create-large-binary-tree] @Aaron Anodide

Comment: You can send me an email at aanodide@gmail.com - sometimes I'm really busy with work but I'll help you if I can

Answer (score 1):

Use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) & [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx)

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
foreach (string s in readText)
{
    string [] split = s.Split(new Char [] {'\t' });
    Console.WriteLine(split[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use File.ReadAllLines() and String.StartWith() and String.Split() method:

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines())
{
   if(line.StartsWith("BANK0")
   {
       string[] words = line.Split("   "); // now these words can be put into their respective arrays
   }
}
```